# Safe to remove snap on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu, uninstall, snap

*I don't use snap and never install snap packages.*

On a new Ubuntu **Server** 18.04, `snap list` shows:

> No snaps are installed yet.

Is it safe to remove it?

I'm not sure what weird dependencies are going on in the background - so I don't want to accidentally break the system now or in the future. (I want to be sure, because on ubuntu desktop, even though I don't use snap, the OS itself does.)

Comment: Over on AU: https://askubuntu.com/questions/878431/can-a-vanilla-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server-run-without-snapd

Comment: @muru Thanks for the pointer! Having so many overlapping StackExchange sites is frustrating.

Comment: I'm leaving this question here instead of deleting it so future readers will have a pointer to the right place instead of opening a new question like I did.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a similar post on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878431/can-a-vanilla-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server-run-without-snapd):

> snapd is seeded in the default install so as to enable snaps to be
>   installed without further work. However, no part of the base install
>   is a snap (you can verify via `snap list`, it should return no snaps).
>   Because of this, snapd can be safely removed with no ill side effects:
>
> ```
> sudo apt purge snapd
> ```
>
> It will probably leave some dependencies lying around. If you want to
>   remove them as well:
>
> ```
> sudo apt autoremove
> ```

The answer is it should be safe to remove it, if you don't intend to use snap.

I don't, and removed it, and nothing bad happened.

Comment: On 20.04 there are some snaps installed now.  I had to do `snap remove` on `lxd`, `core18` and `snapd`.  Possibly in that order, due to dependencies.